Why does my FTS5 search result in "database disk image is malformed"?
Using FTS5 in an SQLite database in C# I get:
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 11: 'database disk image is malformed'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()
   at DatabaseManager.Search(String query) in E:\Documents\projects\sqlite-in-csharp\SqliteExample\DatabaseManager.cs:line 106
   at Program.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Documents\projects\sqlite-in-csharp\SqliteExample\Program.cs:line 42
   at Program.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

On integrity check the meta table comes up clean, but even after rebuilding search is invalid.
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using static DatabaseManager;

namespace Program
{
    public struct Track
    {
        public string Path;
        public string Artist;
        public string Title;

        public Track(string path, string artist, string title)
        {
            Path = path;
            Artist = artist;
            Title = title;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get database connection
            DatabaseManager manager = await DatabaseManager.Build();

            // Insert some data
            Track[] tracks = [
                    new Track("E:/Music/King Gizzard & the Lizard Wizard/Flying Microtonal Banana (2017-02-24)/1.1 - Rattlesnake.flac", "King Gizzard & the Lizard Wizard", "Rattlesnake"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/Tame Impala/Lonerism (2012-10-08)/1.8 - Keep On Lying.flac", "Tame Impala", "Keep On Lying"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/Tame Impala/Lonerism (2012-10-08)/1.4 - Mind Mischief.flac", "Tame Impala", "Mind Mischief"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/Tame Impala/Lonerism (2012-10-08)/1.3 - Apocalypse Dreams.flac", "Tame Impala", "Apocalypse Dreams"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/LCD Soundsystem/This Is Happening (2010-12-03)/1.1 - Dance Yrself Clean.flac", "LCD Soundsystem", "Dance Yrself Clean"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/LCD Soundsystem/LCD Soundsystem (2005-01-24)/1.1 - Daft Punk Is Playing at My House.flac", "LCD Soundsystem", "Daft Punk Is Playing at My House"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/The Silents/Things to Learn (2008-03-28)/1.2 - Ophelia.flac", "The Silents", "Ophelia"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/The Silents/Things to Learn (2008-03-28)/1.4 - Tune for a Nymph.flac", "The Silents", "Tune for a Nymph"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/The Silents/Things to Learn (2008-03-28)/1.6 - Nightcrawl.flac", "The Silents", "Nightcrawl"),
                    new Track("E:/Music/The Silents/Things to Learn (2008-03-28)/1.9 - See the Future.flac", "The Silents", "See the Future"),
            ];
            await manager.InsertData(tracks);

            await manager.Search("\"Tame\"");
        }
    }
}

DatabaseManager.cs:
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Program;

public class DatabaseManager
{
    private SqliteConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public static async Task<DatabaseManager> Build()
    {
        SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=meta.db");
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        DatabaseManager manager = new DatabaseManager(connection);

        await manager.InitTables();

        return manager;
    }

    private DatabaseManager(SqliteConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    private async Task InitTables()
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meta (
                    path TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    artist TEXT,
                    title TEXT
                ) WITHOUT ROWID;
                """;
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            command.CommandText = """
                CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search USING fts5(
                    path UNINDEXED,
                    artist,
                    title,
                    content=meta,
                    content_rowid=path
                );
                """;
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            command.CommandText = """
                CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS meta_ai AFTER INSERT ON meta BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO search(path, artist, title) VALUES (new.path, new.artist, new.title);
                END;
                CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS meta_ad AFTER DELETE ON meta BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO search(search, path, artist, title) VALUES ('delete', old.path, old.artist, old.title);
                END;
                CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS meta_au AFTER UPDATE ON meta BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO search(search, path, artist, title) VALUES ('delete', old.path, old.artist, old.title);
                    INSERT INTO search(path, artist, title) VALUES (new.path, new.artist, new.title);
                END;
                """;
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task InsertData(Track data)
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO meta VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3);";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?1", data.Path);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?2", data.Artist);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?3", data.Title);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task InsertData(Track[] data)
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO meta VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3);";

            var pathParameter = command.Parameters.Add("?1", SqliteType.Text);
            var artistParameter = command.Parameters.Add("?2", SqliteType.Text);
            var titleParameter = command.Parameters.Add("?3", SqliteType.Text);

            foreach (Track track in data)
            {
                pathParameter.Value = track.Path;
                artistParameter.Value = track.Artist;
                titleParameter.Value = track.Title;

                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task Search(string query)
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE search MATCH ?1;";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?1", query);

            var data = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await data.ReadAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
                Console.WriteLine($"{data.GetValue(0)}, {data.GetValue(1)}, {data.GetValue(2)}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Test 2");
        }
    }

    public async Task ResetSanity()
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = """
                INSERT INTO search(search) VALUES ('integrity-check');
                INSERT INTO search(search) VALUES ('rebuild');
                INSERT INTO search(search) VALUES ('integrity-check');
                """;

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}

Is my syntax wrong? Is there something I have to do before matching, or something I have to configure in the virtual table?

As Richard Hipp from the SQLite forum has told me:

You cannot use a WITHOUT ROWID table as an external content table. The external content table must be a rowid table. The "content_rowid=" argument to FTS5 must refer to a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. If you make the "content_rowid=" refer to a TEXT PRIMARY KEY column, it won't work.

Removing the WITHOUT ROWID and content_rowid=path fixes the issue.
